# Cannot access URL http://mywebsite.com/myproject/, return code 22 fatal: git-http-push failed

Tags: git

I've set up a remote git repository on my server.  Here's file and directory structure

```
/var/lib/git/myproject1 ## the git repository for myproject1
/var/lib/git/myproject2 ## the git repository for myproject2

/var/www/mywebwebsite.com/public_html/myproject1  ## symbolic link to /var/lib/git/myproject1
/var/www/mywebwebsite.com/public_html/myproject2  ## symbolic link to /var/lib/git/myproject2
```

Here's what my .gitconfig looks like

```
[core]
    excludesfile = /var/www/.gitignore
[user]
        name = webguy
        email = support@mywebsite.com
```

So from my localhost I successfully ran a `git pull mypro1 master`, where `mypro1` points to `http://mywebsite.com/myproject1`.  The pull downloaded all the files from the remote repository as expected.  But when I do a `git push mypro1 master`, I get the error

```
Cannot access URL http://mywebsite.com/myproject1/, return code 22 fatal: git-http-push failed
```

I get the same error with `myproject2` repository.

Did I set up git or apache incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to enable `dav` to actively push changes over http.  Check out the official [git server over http guide](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/setup-git-server-over-http.txt) for details on how to install it, and other things you may have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following section of your .git/config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
url = http://git.repository.url/repo.git
```

to

```
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
url = http://username:password@git.repository.url/repo.git
```

Then try `git push origin master`.

Edit the authentication details in your config files for other repository URLs as required and push to the required branch.